# parsing the Accept Header in flask-restful for API versioning

Tags: python, flask, versioning

Say I have an accept header like:

```
'Accept: application/vnd.myapp.login.v2+json'
```

and this is sent to the route:

```
/login
```

how would I parse this in flask to get the version number?  I'd assume something like:

```
if request.accept_mimetypes == 'application/vnd.myapp.login.v2+json':
    # use logic for v2
    pass
else:
    # use default logic
    pass
```

But I'd imagine there was a cleaner way to parse this string to ensure the vendor and version are properly specified.

Answer (score 2):

As [flask.Request.headers](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.headers) mentioned:

> The incoming request headers as a dictionary like object.

It maybe look like this:

```
if request.headers['Accept'] == 'application/vnd.myapp.login.v2+json':
    pass
```